# Why do I get a syntax error when I use "given"?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
foreach my $k (keys %rec) {
    #switch for watchlist figures
    given ($k) { #line 93

        # Code omitted

        when ("p") { #positive breakout
            if ($row{cls} > $rec{$k}) {                       
                $email .= "positive";   
            } # line 104            
        }                       
        when ("n") { #negative breakout
            if ($row{cls} < $rec{$k}) { #line 107
```

But I get a syntax error:

```
syntax error at check_watch.pl line 93, near ") {"
syntax error at check_watch.pl line 104, near "}"
Unterminated <> operator at check_watch.pl line 107.
```

Why?

Comment: Very minor nitpick: you shouldn't mix different brace styles, it makes your code hard to read. It doesn't matter *which* style you choose, as long as you're consistent.

Comment: I took the liberty of updating the braces to make the question easier to read for future visitors; I also added an ellipsis since your line numbers were off and I assume you omitted a piece of code.

Answer (score 7):

`given` and `when` are only available when either `use feature "switch";` or `use v5.10;` (or some later value) is in effect.  Place one of those lines at the top of your source file.

Comment: what is the best practice for the use of a switch in production environments?

Comment: @StevieG: I have absolutely no idea.

Comment: @StevieG There was a comment to your answer that was later removed by the author. [`given`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/given.html) feature is experimental so it's best avoided in production environment. You are better off writing `if-then-else` statements to achieve your goal.

Comment: Thank you fellas, Now I don't think my question is of high quality. Should I change the title to make it more general or delete the question?

Answer (score 5):

It is because it is not on by default. Add the line:

```
use 5.10.1;
```

to the code

Answer (score 4):

Because pre-5.10 versions of Perl 5 don't have the `given` or `when` keywords, you're allowed to define custom functions with those names, which of course would have different syntax.  To avoid breaking backward-compatibility with programs that do that, `given` and `when` are only enabled if you specifically ask for them, by putting either

```
use 5.010;
```

or

```
use feature 'switch';
```

at the top of a lexical scope you want to use the keywords in.  In addition, the semantics keep changing.  For example, `given` was originally designed to use lexical `$_` by default, but lexical `$_` turns out to be a really poor fit for Perl 5, an issue they're still revising.  At some point, `given` stopped lexicalizing `$_`, but of course that's a backward-incompatible change.  `when` is (mainly) designed to use `~~`, but that operator had very complicated semantics in 5.10; they've been revised once and there are plans to revise them again.  (This is why the Perl 5 developers have decided to just mark all new features as 'experimental' when they're first included in a development release).

Because they are experimental, to use them without warnings you also need to include:

```
no if $] >= 5.017011, warnings => 'experimental::smartmatch';
```

or add a 5.18 dependency and use

```
no warnings 'experimental::smartmatch';
```

, or add a dependency on the `experimental` CPAN module and use

```
use experimental 'smartmatch';
```

.

Now, on the other hand, the Perl 5 developers (of course) need people to use `given`, `when`, and `~~` in non-production-critical (or thoroughly unit-tested!) code and give them feedback.  So definitely do use them if you can.